How can I remove an Excel worksheet from a VSTO project after the project has been created?
I created a VSTO Excel document project from an existing Excel file.
In that Excel file there is a workbook containing two worksheets.
Now, I want to remove the second worksheet from the project, but there is no "Remove" or "Delete" menu item for the corresponding node in Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer.
How can I remove/delete redundant Excel worksheets from an existing VSTO Excel document project?

I couldn't find a method for this. You might try deleting the sheet in Excel and then updating the corresponding VSTP Project.
